# Anaconda + wine - Switch env

Tags: python, anaconda, wine

Want to use py2exe in wine.
Appears to be broken in python 3.5

Installed Anaconda 4.2.0 with python 3.5

Created new env:

```
wine conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
wine conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
py34           C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\envs\py34
root         * C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3

wine activate py34
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\activate.exe"
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

```
wine cmd
activate py34
```

gives me loads of errors

> Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601 (1.9.23)
>
> Z:\home\john\dev\etikett_amoinst>activate py34
>
> Z:\home\john\dev\etikett_amoinst>:: this finds either --help or -h and
>   shows the help text Can't recognise 'C:\windows\System32\find.exe /I
>   "-h" ' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
>       @call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Scripts\..\Scripts\conda.exe" ..activate "cmd.exe" -h
>   ) else (
>       :: reset errorlevel to 0
>       cmd /c "exit /b 0" )
>
> Z:\home\john\dev\etikett_amoinst>:: this finds either --help or -h and
>   shows the help text Can't recognise 'C:\windows\System32\find.exe /I
>   "-h" ' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
>       @call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Scripts\..\Scripts\conda.exe" ..deactivate "cmd.exe"
>   -h ) else (
>       :: reset errorlevel to 0
>       cmd /c "exit /b 0" )
>               REM Run any deactivate scripts
>               @IF EXIST "\etc\conda\deactivate.d" (
>                   @PUSHD "\etc\conda\deactivate.d"
>                   @FOR %g IN (*.bat) DO @CALL "%g"
>
> Z:\home\john\dev\etikett_amoinst>) Can't recognise ')' as an internal
>   or external command, or batch script.
>
> Z:\home\john\dev\etikett_amoinst>) Can't recognise ')' as an internal
>   or external command, or batch script.
>
> Z:\home\john\dev\etikett_amoinst>

Comment: The conda activate script is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Scripts`. You have to add that directory to your path

Comment: That path is included in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path

Comment: This might just be broken on Wine. I'm not sure whether anyone's ever tested it. You might want to make a post on the conda Github issues page (or search there)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of py2exe you can try to use pyinstaller.

On MacOS I had a lot of problems with running the miniconda `activate` script under wine as well. For me he solution was to use winetricks and install cmd (`winetricks cmd`) and configure wine as windows 10 (`winetricks win10`).

After that, running

```
wine cmd
activate
```

behaved as expected.